# JavascriptExecutor within Selenium script throws “org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: javascript error”

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to pass value to a calendar field using `JavascriptExecutor` in my Selenium code.

The method declaration is as follows:

```java
public static void selectDepDate(WebDriver driver, String value) {
    js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    js.executeScript("arguments[0].removeAttribute('readonly', 0)", deptDate);
    js.executeScript("arguments[0].value=''", deptDate);
    js.executeScript("arguments[0].value='" + value + "')", deptDate);
}
```

I am calling the method via `selectDepDate(driver, "15-Sep-2020")`.

Upon execution of the script, I am seeing the following exception in the console logs:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException:
javascript error: Unexpected token ')'
```

Comment: At which line are you getting the error?

Comment: js.executeScript("arguments[0].value='" + value + "')", deptDate);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have a reference to your webElement, You can use `setAttribute` with below approach to set the value.

```
 driver.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute(arguments[1], arguments[2]);", 
                deptDate, attributeName, value);
```

Here `attributeName` is the name of `attribute` to which you want to set date inside `deptDate webElement`.